# In which direction is this statement true?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Having a hard time how I would go at this question.

$\exists x \in G, P(x) \wedge Q(x) \iff
    (\exists x \in G, P(x)) \wedge (\exists x \in G, Q(x))$

$\forall x \in D, P(x) \vee Q(x) \iff
    (\forall x \in D, P(x)) \vee (\forall x \in D, Q(x))$

Comment: Let $G=D=\{0,1\}$ for simplicity. Try different things for $P$ and $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** 
Note that in the first bi-conditional, RHS is true whenever LHS is true, since if there is a single thing with both properties *P* and *Q* (LHS)---say a *Pink Queen*, then it *does* follow that there is something *Pink* and that there is a *Queen*. If this is a material bi-conditional, then even when LHS is false or impossible the '$\Longrightarrow$' direction will be true. Consequently the '$\Longrightarrow$' direction of the first formula is always true (valid). The '$\Longleftarrow$' direction isn't valid however, for suppose there is something *Pink* and there is a thing that is a *Queen*, but the *Pink* thing and the thing that is a *Queen* needn't be the same thing---the thing that is a *Queen* may be *White* (say), and as such not *Pink*. Try to use similar reasoning for the second bi-conditional.

**Hint 2:**
You may want to construct a counter-model for either of the directions. Here two-item models will suffice, as suggested by $\color{navy}{\text{columbus8myhw}}$ above. 
Let $G=D=\{ a,b\}$, and recall that for finite domains $D$, $\exists x \in D, P(x)$ is equivalent to $P(a_1) \lor P(a_2) \lor...\lor P(a_n)$ for an *n* sized domain, and $\forall x \in D, P(x)$ is equivalent to $P(a_1) \land P(a_2) \land...\land P(a_n)$. This gives you a way to transform those FOL frormulae into PC formulae, the validity of which you can check using semantic trees or truth tables, if no obvious countermodels come to mind.

**Hint 3:** The first bi-conditional for a two element model would be equivalent to the formula $( P(a) \land Q(a)) \lor ( P(b) \land Q(b)) \iff ( P(a) \lor P(b)) \land ( Q(a) \lor Q(b))$. Now consider the model where $P=\{a \}$ and $Q=\{b \}$, and note that this is a counter-model for the '$\Longleftarrow$' direction, since the RHS conjunction is true since both of its conjuncts are true, i.e. $P(a)$ and $Q(b)$ is true on this model, and LHS disjunction isn't true since both of its disjuncts fail to be true on account of there being an absence of an object $\alpha \in G$ such that both $P(\alpha)$ and $Q(\alpha)$.

The above counter-model is merely a formalization of the earlier counterexample given in Hint 1: think of $a$ as the *Pink* thing in $G$, and $b$ as the *Queen* in $G$, but that doesn't entail that there needs to be a *single* object in $G$ that is both a *Queen* and *Pink*. Hope that helps.